# using multiple parameter with url rewrite php

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite, hyperlink, uri

hi am trying to use url rewrite with php with this code

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #prevent access to (includes) folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([includes])$ /new [L]
    #if use tow parameter
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [L]
    #if use one parameter
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([a-z0-9]+)
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?p1=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

and i have an index.php file that content two links 
first one send one parameter
second send tow parameter

```
<a href="parameter1">one parameter</a>
<a href="parameter1/parameter2">two parameter</a>
```

when I use the first link every thing is ok and the link is showing in browser as

```
http://localhost/project/parameter1
```

when I use the second link at the first time every thing look good too as

```
http://localhost/project/parameter1/parameter2
```

but if I repress the link again the link is showing in browser as

```
http://localhost/project/parameter1/parameter1/parameter2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal behavior. Remember as far as the web browser (resolving your link adresses) is concerned, your parameters show up in the URL as directories.

```
<a href="parameter1">one parameter</a>
<a href="parameter1/parameter2">two parameter</a>
```

First link indicates to visit the resource "parameter1" in current directory.
Second link indicates to visit the resource "parameter2" in the parameter1 subdirectory (relative to your current directory).

You could change the link urls to be relative to the root path (mentioning the `project` directory of course), which would solve the issue (the magic is all contained in the first `/` here):

```
<a href="/project/parameter1">one parameter</a>
<a href="/project/parameter1/parameter2">two parameter</a>
```